# Locating ID number and copying to cell in another column using Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a specific cell value that signifies that the cell next to it is the ID of my object (in this case the object ID of a shapefile feature).

[image]

and

[image]

I'd like to copy this ID into every cell in the column next to the XY coordinates. Like to:

[image]

The number copied should coincide with the last ID, which comes up with the ;9.

I've tried this, but it does not update the ID number automatically.

[image]

Now, I've tried this, but it gives me this error:

[image]

Still some errors with this update. It's only one every few entries.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hack job you could try something like this:

```
=if(isblank(b2),a1,(if(b2=";9",c2,n/a)
```

It'll look at the B column and if its blank take the value of the cell above, if there is something there, it'll check for your anchor of ;9 and take the value of the opposing cell providing the value for all the one below it.

I'm not sure weather its important to keep the cell blank in column A next to the anchor, if it is, just reference everything a cell higher like so:

In A2:

```
=if(isblank(b1),A1,(if(b1=";9",c1,n/a)
```

Comment: I think you're on the right page, it looks like there must be something in column B, try changing it to: "A2: =if(b1=0,A1,(if(b1=";9",c1,n/a) or b1=""

Comment: it still gives an error for all cells unless it's the first cell below the ;9. The way it's shown in the last screen capture.

Comment: ok, this should do it, I'll flip the if conditions:
=IF(b1=";9",c1,A1) 
Start this from a2